# on-click of button in controller1 , function from controller2 should be executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On-click of button in `controller1`, function present in `controller2` should be called.
I have tried using service, no luck though.

check the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bkD1iR3LBk2pAayQ7wCe?p=preview) for the code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: for code check plunkr :https://plnkr.co/edit/bkD1iR3LBk2pAayQ7wCe?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using service, use `broadcast` to call a method from an another controller.

```
.controller('ctrl', [
        '$scope', 'svc',
        function($scope, svc) {
            $scope.fun = function() {
                $scope.$emit('sampleEvent')
            }
        }
    ])
    .controller('ctrl1', [
        '$scope', 'svc', '$rootScope',
        function($scope, svc, $rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('sampleEvent', function(ev) {
                $scope.fun2()
            })
            $scope.fun2 = function() {
                alert("hi");
            }
        }
    ]);
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PrbGcrpvXuOjp3MLAhcq?p=preview)

Comment: yes,it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

well if you really want to do it with service you can do it like this

```
 (function() {
        angular.module('app', [])
            .service('svc', function() {
                var svc = {};

                svc.method = function() {
                   // And here you can call it
                    svc.fun2();
                    //on click from first controller it should open a alert box saying "hi"

                }
                return svc;
            })
            .controller('ctrl', [
                '$scope', 'svc', function($scope, svc) {
                  $scope.fun = function(){
                    svc.method();
                  }
                }
            ])
            .controller('ctrl1', [
                '$scope', 'svc', function($scope, svc) {

                    $scope.fun2 = function(){
                      alert("hi");
                    }

                   // inject your method to your service here when method is defined
                    svc.fun2 = $scope.fun2;
                }
            ]); 
    })();
```

Comment: yes it works as expected..